# Does SQL Server 2008 express allow remote connections?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

I have tried to remotely connect to SQL. I put in port 1433, I restarted the service, and I don't have Windows' firewall active. However, I can only use local connection, I can't remotely connect.

I read that SQL Server 2005 Express doesn't allow remote connection, but what about 2008? Does it allow remote connections?

Comment: Please provide a link to where you read this.

Comment: When you were reading whatever you were reading you either missed the phrase `by default` or the source is wrong. All SQL Servers install with remote connection turned off and you have to turn it on explicitly via a variety of steps which differ somewhat between versions.

Comment: @i  have tried to do a remote connection, and i dont get it @Paul

Comment: That simply means that you have more configuration to do. Go to the link that DWRoelands suggested and follow ALL the steps. For example, from your description what you tried, you never mention whether you went to server properties via SSMS and the Connections tab and checked the Allow Remote Connections check box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to setup the server to accept tcp/ip connections.

This is done through the [SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx).

Start the manager, navigate to your server node and enable `TCP/IP` connections on it.